# How to display different sql data in a text box when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, mysql

My `MySql` database consists of a column `id` which contains numbers from 1 to 30. I want to display the number 1 to 30 in a text box each time a button is pressed. However, my code displays only first row that is 1.

I have tried following code:

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUMIT;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True"); 
SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from id", Conn); 
Conn.Open(); 
SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();

if (DR1.Read()) {
    textBox3.Text = DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
Conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways of doing this.

First Using SQL

Keep the count of the number outside the button click function

```
int BtnCount = 0;
```

and in Button Click

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUMIT;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True"); 
SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from id WHERE ID = " + BtnCount  , Conn); 
Conn.Open(); 
SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();

if (DR1.Read()) {
    textBox3.Text = DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
Conn.Close();
BtnCount ++;
if(BtnCount>30)
{
    BtnCount = 0;
}
```

Secondly you can call all the data in the collection / list / array which will also enhance the speed of your system

Create the list of strings

```
List<string> ListData = new List<string>();
```

Populate the list at the constructor like this

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUMIT;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True"); 
SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from id WHERE ID = " + BtnCount  , Conn); 
Conn.Open(); 
SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();

while(DR1.Read()) 
{
    ListData.Add(DR1.GetValue(0).ToString());
}
Conn.Close();
```

And on Button Click show the content of the list by `BtnCount`

***Note***: It is just to give you the idea I havent run the program to test.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is you have all that code in your button click event. So every time you click the button, it creates a new connection, executes the query and shows you the first record.

I recommend you reorganize your code.

For example, call the `SetupData()` function once(maybe on load time or anywhere as long as it is executed only once) then click the button click event will only contain the if statement.

```
SqlDataReader DR1;
public void SetupData(){
     SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUMIT;Initial          Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True"); 
     SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from id", Conn); 
     Conn.Open(); 
     DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();
}

 void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            if (DR1.Read()) {
                textBox3.Text = DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Yohannes. thanks for the code you provided but your code displayed all the data(1-30) in text box but what I asked was.data(1-30) should display seperately when button is clicked.for example when button is clicked first time it should display 1, when button is clicked second time it should display 2 and so on.

Comment: Hey, I've changed the answer. Your main problem is, since your button click event initializes a new connection and executes the query which sets the data pointer to the first record, the DR1.Read() will always point to the first record.